# Correct database to build: relational or document store?

Tags: database-design

I would like to create a research database that mainly will return user-created .pdfs but that can arithmetically manipulate information in the documents or perhaps tagged meta-data. Is the right approach a traditional relational database like Access, or a NoSQL database like MongoDB? Eventually I'd like to create an internal company website as a front-end for the reports.

Comment: Why not both?  Use a relational database for the metadata and a document database for the PDF files.

Comment: thanks! I'm such a newbie that I don't really know how it all works - I imagined it would be easier to integrate into a website if it was one database?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of any database server that can arithmetically manipulate information in [Portable Document Format (PDF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF) documents.

You will need to parse your PDF documents outside your database. Pull out the important parts. If there are a fixed set of specific values within each PDF, store those in column fields of one table. The PDF document can be stored in a column of the same table.

If by "tagged meta-data" you mean a collection of zero, one, or more tag values to associate with each PDF document, then you will use additional table(s).

I would suggest using a relational database like [Postgres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) that can store your PDF as a binary large object type, often called [BLOB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object). See this page on the [binary data types in Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-binary.html).